# Get current path of Automator app

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, automator, install

I am trying to create an Automator application which I will be distributing to other users on the network. The automator app will be accompanied by a ZIP file and a PKG installer file.

I need to run the PKG installer file the automator app. For this I'm trying to use the Run Shell Script using the following command:

```
open gdata.pkg
```

The problem I'm having is that Automator cannot find this file. I think it doesn't pick up the current path. I tried changing it to following ways:

Experiment #1:

```
cd $@; open gdata.pkg
```

Experiment #2:

```
open ./gdata.pkg
```

Both didn't work for me. Automator keeps giving error that it couldn't run the script. How do I accomplish this here?

My next step after this would be to decompress the accompanied ZIP file onto a new folder on user's desktop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a Run AppleScript action with the following to get the path:

```
POSIX path of (path to me)
```

When run in the workflow, this provides the path to Automator.app, but when run by launching the saved application, this provides the path to the application.

Comment: Ok that was a good lead. I've managed to develop a code to make it happen: 'set pathToMe to POSIX path of (path to me as text)', and (set script1 to "dirname '" & pathToMe & "'"), and (set dirPath to do shell script script1), then finally (do shell script "open '" & dirPath & "/GData.pkg'"). I'm not sure if this is the best way to make this work.

Answer (score -3):

I'd post the answer here, but this article already fully captures it, so *shrug*:

http://albertech.blogspot.com/2011/08/get-path-of-running-script-with.html

Comment: As apt as the article might be, sometimes they get taken offline, so we'd appreciate it if you quoted or paraphrased it here.

Comment: The question already has an accepted answer and your _link only_ answer provides the same thing `(path to me)` and therefore is needlessly redundant!